# tk.Text: Offsetting bgstipple

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The script below will create an `xbm` file that is just a vertical line positioned at either the left, right or center of the `xbm`. When the `xbm` is used for `bgstipple` everything is offset by half of a character width, but without wrap! If I left align the line in the `xbm`, it appears in the center when used as stipple. If I center align in the `xbm`, it appears at the end of the character as stipple. If I right align the line it does not appear, at all. I've used other built-in `xbm`s and they do not have this behavior. What am I doing wrong? The below reproduces this behavior 100% of the time, for me.

```
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.font as tkf
import math


class Text(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **dict(font='{Courier New} 14',wrap="none",exportselection=1,takefocus=1))
        self.make_caret_xbm('caret.xbm', self['font'])
        
    def make_caret_xbm(self, path, font, inswidth=1) -> None:
        #prepare
        f    = tkf.Font(font=font)
        h, w = f.metrics('linespace'), f.measure(' ')
        d, m = divmod(w, 8)
        bl   = d+(m>0)
        wtmz = f'{"0"*(bl*8)}'
        
        #line at beginning ~ appears in center of character
        lt = f'{"1"*inswidth}{wtmz}'
        
        #line in middle ~ appears at end of character
        cn = f'{"0"*(math.ceil(w/2))}{"1"*inswidth}{wtmz}'
        
        #line at end ~ does not appear
        rt = f'{"0"*(w-inswidth)}{"1"*inswidth}{wtmz}'
        
        #---set-line-type-here---vv
        row  = ','.join(hex(int( lt[(n:=int(i*8)):n+8] ,2)) for i in range(bl))
        
        xbmdata  = ',\n\t'.join(row for i in range(h))
        xbmdata  = (f"#define image_width {w}\n#define image_height {h}\n"
                    "static unsigned char image_bits[] = {\n\t"
                    f'{xbmdata}}};')
                    
        print(xbmdata)
        #save xbm
        with open(path, 'wb') as f: f.write(xbmdata.encode())
        
    def caret(self):
        #create the caret tag and add it to everything
        self.tag_configure('CARET',bgstipple="@caret.xbm",background='#FF0000')
        self.tag_add('CARET','1.0','end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class App(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            #config cell
            self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure   (0, weight=1)
            #instantiate editor
            (ed := Text(self)).grid(sticky='nswe')
            #insert text and apply caret to everything
            ed.insert('1.0', 'Hello World')
            ed.caret()
    #run        
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you examine the XBM you created? You created a XBM with a vertical line around middle of the image when you want the vertical line at the left side of the image.

Comment: @acw1668 ~ Thanks. I either read a poor xbm format explanation or understood it poorly. It said: a bit per pixel, and it drops any excess lower bits that overflow a row. By observation, the bits are actually backwards and it drops the upper bits. I would never have tested this if you wouldn't have said something. However, there is still an offset of 8 in tkinter, and it, as-well-as `padx` have to be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xbm` maker is backwards in logic. Assuming we had a width of 8 (to keep it simple) a line on the left would repeat this: `00000001`. Unfortunately, it isn't that simple when trying to make a line ride the edge of text. Firstly, you have to determine the window offset with `master.winfo_rootx()-master.winfo_x()`, where "master" is referring to the toplevel window. Secondly, the `padx` property needs to be considered.

The below rewrite works for me, for fixed-width fonts between 12 and 96. It may work for other sizes, but I only tried 12 to 96. Bits are flipped so it fills the background, except for the caret. This allows the "caret" to inherit the `background` property of the WIDGET, and the stipple will inherit the `background` property of whatever TAG it shares a spot with. It produces a very convincing caret. The one drawback is you have to tag the entire text widget with a background color that isn't identical to the caret.

I actually only ever tag the entire document when in boxselect or multicaret mode. It flips the widget's `background` and `insertbackground` attributes, adding a "background" tag to everything. When neither of those modes are active it flips back and removes the tag.

```
    #make caret xbm
    @staticmethod
    def caretxbm(w:int, iw:int, px:int, wo:int) -> None:
        iw   = min(w,iw)    #cap 'insertwidth' to width
        d, m = divmod(w, 8)
        b    = d+(m>0)      #total byte count for this xbm
        o    = wo+px        #window offset + padx
        bl   = b*8-(iw+o)   #number of remaining bits
        
        #final bits
        bits = f'{"1"*bl}{"0"*iw}{"1"*o}'
            
        #only one pixel tall because it will repeat
        row  = ','.join(hex(int(bits[(n:=int(i*8)):n+8] ,2)) for i in range(b))
        xbm  = (f"#define image_width {w}\n#define image_height 1\n"
                "static unsigned char image_bits[] = {\n\t"
                f'{row}}};')
                    
        with open(f'caret_{w}_{iw}_{px}_{wo}.xbm', 'wb') as f: f.write(xbm.encode())
```